# What is preventing my angular2 CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass from being GC'd?

Tags: javascript, angular, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I'm trying to debug a memory leak in my angular2 application.
I have a testcase:

- I navigate between 2 routes of my application.
- I take a memory snapshot after only navigating a few times.
- Then i navigate ~100 times and take another snapshot.

When i compare the snapshots i see:

- snapshot 1 has **45** CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass objects.
- snapshot 2 has **2551** CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass objects.

So it seems the entire compiledTemplates are not being GC'd.

But now the problem is that i can't seem to figure out the cause/source of the leak..

Here's how the CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass objects look in the dev tools:

[image: ChromeMemSnapshot]

As far as i understand i should look at the topmost entry in the retainers object view.
In my case this is the compView_3 in View_EmployeesListComponent8.

So i lookup this object and it shows _view in DebugContext as topmost retainer object:

[image: View_EmployeesListComponent8 retainers object]

But i don't think that's where i should be looking.
Could anyone please point me in the right direction to find the cause of this memory leak?